# Sales Console and Service Console App can not be edited from App Manager

Tags: sales, service-console

We accidentally removed the following two items from production org:

- LightningSalesConsole_UtilityBar
- LightningService_UtilityBar

Now both Sales Console and Service Console app can not be edited from the App Manager.

Is there any way to recover those two apps?

When we try to edit, we find the below image:
[image]

Comment: I know this was a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CyUQAU) , but it says it was fixed in Winter '22. What does it say when you try to edit the apps?

Comment: It did not give any warning.

Comment: So what happens when you try to edit? Or is the edit button missing? Screenshots or specifics would be helpful to understand what's the current issue

Comment: The edit button is showing. But we find an error message. I have updated the image in the description.

Comment: your best bet will be to create a support case and provide that error ID. It seems that  the known issue I linked should block you from deleting the utility bar of a standard application now (so you don't run into this situation) - but, it seems you did successfully delete it.

Comment: Thank you @KrisGoncalves for your comment.